# How to use that API? React fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, fetch-api

I need help with a small project. I want to do app in React with API that consists of two parts :

1. field of type `search` to enter the artist or title of the work
2. a list of results that meet the search condition, in which each item contains:
   a. Artist
   b. Title of the work
   c. Type of tabulation

API link: https://www.songsterr.com/a/wa/api

That's what I've made, but I have some problems:
How I have to use fetch to catch all the songs?
How to do this:

1. The user can enter the name of the work or artist in the search field.
2. When you click the `Search` button, you get a list with the results.

```
class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        searchValue: '',
        songs: []
    };
    handleOnChange = event => {
        this.setState({searchValue: event.target.value})
    }
    handleSearch = () => {
        this.makeApiCall(this.state.SearchValue)
    }

    makeApiCall = searchInput => {
        let api_url = `?????????'

        fetch(api_url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <>
         <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <input name="text" type="search" placeholder="Search" onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)} value={this.state.SearchValue}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
        {this.state.songs ? (
            <div>
                {this.state.songs.map((song, index)=>(
                <div key={index}>
                    <h1>{song.nameWithoutThePrefix}</h1>
                </div>    

                    
                 )) }
            </div>

        ) : (
            <p>Something</p>
        )}
        </>
        )}
}
```

I know that to divide this App to smaller components, but before that I wanted to do all logic of this app. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this was down voted but here is a working sample

[Sandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/tomsoon-stackoverdlow-mmxsv)

Based on the link provided, the json api search by artist endpoint is:

```
https://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/byartists.json?artists={comma seperated artists names}
```

Snippet

```
import React from "react";

class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchValue: "",
    songs: []
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSearch = () => {
    this.makeApiCall(this.state.searchValue);
  };

  makeApiCall = async (searchInput) => {
    let api_url = `https://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/byartists.json?artists=${searchInput}`;

    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const songs = await response.json();

    this.setState({ songs });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <input
          name="text"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
          value={this.state.SearchValue}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
        {this.state.songs ? (
          <div>
            {this.state.songs.map((song, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <h1>{song.title}</h1>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>Something</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```